# $sscanf doesn't return or sets values in Questasim

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

I've a major compatibility issue with my system verilog code.

I have this line:
`c = $sscanf(line, "0x%x %s %s %d", hex_value, type, name, size);`

Using the vcs compiler yields the result:
`c = 4, hex_value = 0x001, type = "empty", name = "mem_block", size = 8`

While using Questasim `vlog -sv` and `vsim -c` yields the result:
`c = 0, hex_value = 0x000, type = "", name = "", size = 0`

Does anyone know a solution for this or another string scan function?

Edit:

I found the reason why I didn't get the correct output printed.
I used:

`display($sformatf("c=%d, hex_value = %x, type=%s, size=%s", c, hex_value, type, name, size));`

Changed this to `$display($sformatf(line, "c=%d, hex_value = %x, type=%s, size=%s", c, hex_value, type, name, size));` and it worked like a charm in Questasim but not in VCS. I still have the problem about `c` being returned as `0` from `$sscanf` also it does not set values to `hex_value` etc.

Edit 2:

Found the problem but not a solution

The cause of the bug/problem is `0x%x` where VCS needs this to not put something like `0x0f1` while in Questasim this causes all the values to be defaulted to 0, so that `c=0, hex_value=0x00, type=""` etc. Does anyone know a good way to solve this? I tried different combinations of `0x` and `x0` before the `%x` but nothing seems to work.
`hex_value` is defined like this `typedef bit unsigned [63:0] hex_addr_t;`

Comment: FYI, `type` is a SystemVerilog keyword and should cause problems, rename it (ex `_type` or `type_`). Why are you putting `$sformatf` inside `$display`? Try: `$display("c=%d, hex_value = %x, type=%s, name=%s, size=%d", c, hex_value, _type, name, size);` or `output_msg = $sformatf("c=%d, hex_value = %x, type=%s, name=%s, size=%d", c, hex_value, _type, name, size); $display("%s", output_msg);`

Comment: Ah yeah sorry a bit new to system-verilog

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, I have hex values with 0x in front of the values unfortunately this does scanned by `$sscanf` in VCS and will then default then hex to `0x0f1` and by adding `0x` in VCS `$sscanf` skips the `0x` part. Unfortunately this causes Questasim to default all values given by `$sscanf` to `0` because it doesn't know what to do with the specifier. The solution to this was using a for loop to check for the 1st occurrence of `x` then replace it with `0` using `str.putc(len_to_x, "0")`.